# WCF Routing with Content Transformation

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-routing

I've implemented a WCF Routing service; I would also like the service (or a similar WCF service) to transform the payload in a prescribed and uniform (content-agnostic) fashion. For example, the payload will always take the form `Foo<T>` and I would like to pass it on as `Bar<T>` in all cases. I'm happy for the transformation to be XSLT or programmatic. I don't care what happens to messages received that aren't of the type `Foo<T>`.

I wish to use WCF as it provides a lot of OOTB functionality (e.g. its support for numerous bindings). It's not practical to implement a WCF service with numerous boilerplate methods to transform each closed generic (`Foo<Class1>` -> `Bar<Class1>`; `Foo<Class2>` -> `Bar<Class2>`; etc), as this would require recompilation/redeployment every time a new message type was to be routed.

To the best of my knowledge, WCF doesn't handle open generics and WCF Routing doesn't facilitate content transformation OOTB. That said, `System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService` obviously intercepts WCF calls in some non-specific form, so I was hoping to leverage the same pattern to achieve my goal. Can anyone  please provide direction on how to do this (or indicate why it's not possible)?

Comment: It is probably possible on low level message processing to implement any kind of XML based transformation but I think you will not find a general support for that because of two reasons based around the one core idea: MS already have tools prepared for routing and transformation: Workflow services for easy scenarios and BizTalk Server for real application integration.

Comment: This seems to be possible using an IDispatchMessageInspector.

Comment: Yes, but I never finished off the code (requirements changed and priorities shifted). Essentially, I created a class that implemented the IDispatchMessageInspector and performed a transform in there. That worked (which is the solution to my question above). I can't share the code I wrote (due to my contract), but I will reimplement something similar at home and post it. My end goal, however, was a bit more than that though...

Comment: I really wanted to intercept a call to a signature like "Guid DoStuff(Foo<T> foo)" and multicast it to a signature like "void DoStuff(Bar<T> bar)". The Guid would be a tracing ID and would get embedded in 'bar' as well. If the calling method expects a response, the multicast will return an exception. My end goal was to intercept this exception (in BeforeSendReply) and replace it with a reply that returned the Guid. My XSLT is very rusty though, so I never finished the code. Hopefully someone else can finish it when I post.

Comment: @hugh Sorry for not posting the code sooner - I didn't get a chance to work on it till Easter. Please see the snippet below and let me know if you want a full solution that works for the scenario I mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suggested in my comments on the question, there is a solution to this using the IDispatchMessageInspector. Please find below an extremely dumbed-down version of what I ended up writing (easier than me posting the code for 20 classes). If anyone wants a full solution implementing this code in a significantly cleaner and more advanced manner, let me know and I'll put my demo up on CodeProject. For now, I'll presume you're happy with a snippet of the guts.

The Console commands can obvious be removed (they're just so you can debug if you're self-hosting).

```
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        if (request == null || request.IsEmpty)
            return null;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(request);
        Console.ResetColor();

        // Load the request into a document.
        XPathDocument document;
        MemoryStream stream;
        using (stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(stream))
            {
                request.WriteMessage(writer);
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0L;
                document = new XPathDocument(stream);
            }
        }

        // Load the XSLT.
        XslCompiledTransform transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
        transformer.Load("RequestTransformation.xslt");

        // Transform the document.
        byte[] transformedDocument;
        using (stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            transformer.Transform(document, null, stream);
            transformedDocument = stream.ToArray();
        }

        // Construct new request from tranformed document.
        stream = new MemoryStream(transformedDocument);
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
        Message modifiedMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, request.Version);
        modifiedMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(request.Properties);
        request = modifiedMessage;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false).GetString(transformedDocument));
        Console.ResetColor();

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I'd very much like to see the full solution. Let me know if you had time to write the article. Thanks.